# Wamp server to android physical device connection?

Tags: android, wamp

I have a wamp server. I have written my android client. If I run that app, the response is fine on an emulator...but the same code does not work on the real device, I mean I dont get a response.....

Here s the code...

```
public static final String SERVER_URL = "http://192.168.1.3/AndroidListServer/server.php?command=getAnimalList";
private static String executeHttpRequest(String data) {
  String result = "";
  try {
   URL url = new URL(SERVER_URL);
   URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

   /*
    * We need to make sure we specify that we want to provide input and
    * get output from this connection. We also want to disable caching,
    * so that we get the most up-to-date result. And, we need to 
    * specify the correct content type for our data.
    */
   connection.setDoInput(true);
   connection.setDoOutput(true);
   connection.setUseCaches(false);
   connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

   // Send the POST data
   DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
   dataOut.writeBytes(data);
   dataOut.flush();
   dataOut.close();

   // get the response from the server and store it in result
   DataInputStream dataIn = new DataInputStream(connection.getInputStream()); 
   String inputLine;
   while ((inputLine = dataIn.readLine()) != null) {
    result += inputLine;
   }
   dataIn.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   /*
    * In case of an error, we're going to return a null String. This
    * can be changed to a specific error message format if the client
    * wants to do some error handling. For our simple app, we're just
    * going to use the null to communicate a general error in
    * retrieving the data.
    */
   e.printStackTrace();
   result = null;
  }

  return result;
 }
```

Comment: Rajesh sorry, Am working on a networking project. I needed to showcase a client-server app. The client code is as shown. The server, if its connecting to a wamp server on the emulator responds with the list that we want. But if connected to a physical device it returns empty..Am I clear, Rajesh?

Comment: I guess it has to do with the wamp URL...but I have been trying to figure this from yesterday..had a lot of research done on the net, but to no avail....:(

Comment: Make sure that the device is in the same network as the server. You may have to use WiFi or check Abdullah Jibaly's answer below for using port forwarding. The server IP 192.168.x.x is a private IP and will not be visible from outside the network (for example, if you are using the cellular data network).

Comment: Am using a wi-fi for both my laptop and the device...So it has to be on the same network...Dont have any SIM inserted into the device too...

Comment: You can check if there are any connectivity problems between the device and the server. You may also check if there is any firewall on the server preventing the connectivity.

Comment: Yes Rajesh, it was the firewall issue.......thanks a lot for this view.....and yes ME BAD :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it guys....it was the problem with the firewall as Rajesh mentioned...I should do a thorough testing of all the possible parameters....but hey I'm learning :)